# Forms with template variables

Tags: django, django-crispy-forms

This has two questions in one. I am surveying a group of students. I've got survey objects, student objects and crispy ModelForms.

Within my crispy ModelForm I am using `self.helper.layout` and I've got a template tag in there...

```
self.helper.layout = Layout(
            'surveyset', # won't display this eventually
            'student', # this will also be hidden
            # ...
            HTML("""
            <p>Complete this scale using your knowledge of <b>{{form.student}}</b> during this school year.</p>
""")
```

Now how do I set up my view to

1. Send partially-filled survey forms with student field filled out
2. Allow `{{form.student))` to be rendered in the template.

This is what I have so far... i'll need to use a `FormSet` but we'll cross that bridge when we get there...

```
def select_and_rate(request):
    classrooms = Classroom.objects.filter(user=request.user)

    return render(request, "reports/select-students.html", {'classrooms':classrooms})


@login_required
def screen_many(request):

    # All right we're gonna have a set of surveys!
    ss = SurveySet()
    ss.save()

    # Sorting...
    i1 = sorted([(k,v) for k,v in request.POST.items() if k[:2] == 'i_'], key=itemgetter(1))
    e1 = sorted([(k,v) for k,v in request.POST.items() if k[:2] == 'e_'], key=itemgetter(1))

    i = [int(v) for k,v in request.POST.items() if k[:2] == 'i_']
    e = [int(v) for k,v in request.POST.items() if k[:2] == 'e_']

    i_students = Student.objects.filter(pk__in=i)
    e_students = Student.objects.filter(pk__in=e)

    # make a formset with a bunch of surveys with surveyset FK and student FK filled out
    # prefilled_survey = Survey(student=stu, surveyset=ss)
    # sform = SurveyForm(request.POST or None, instance=prefilled_survey)

    # SurveyFormSet = formset_factory(sform,form=SurveyForm, extra=len(e)+len(i))

    # some how fit form to intern/extern attribute (minus parts)
    # make a new surveyset

    # make lists of tuples sorted by key
    survey = Survey(surveyset=ss, student=i_students[0])

    form = SurveyForm(request.POST or None, )
    if form.is_valid():
        saved = form.save(commit=False)
        saved.surveyset = ss
        saved.student = i_students[0]
        saved.save()
        messages.success(request, "submitted.")

    return render_to_response("reports/screen_many.html", 
                                locals(),
                                context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Thanks!